# htaccess adding a slash on the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to send all requests for a flv file to a download script.

In my htaccess I have added

```
RewriteRule ^/flashvideos/(.+).flv$  download.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so requests for `http://website/flashvideos/3791.flv` will go to `http://website/download.php?id=3791`, but instead they go to `http://website/flashvideos/3791.flv/`

I cannot see a rule anywhere in the htaccess file which does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out what was happening. I had the format wrong. This works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/flashvideos/(.+).flv$
RewriteRule .  download.php?id=$1 [L]
```